# How to calculate a column with different currencies to a new column with the same currency

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, subset, dplyr

I'm in a bit of a R-dilemma.

I am working with a dataset, which is a project portfolio, where I have a column named: **Currency** (which lists a total of 60 different currenices worldwide fx. USD, Euro, GBR) and another column named: **Total Amount**, which is the actual total amount of that currency on a given project.

My dilemma, is that i want to re-calculate all the projetcs into 1 specific currency, Euro.

I have been able to do this, one currency at a time, by first creating a new dataframe, where I subset my data (Projects) with a specific currency fx GBR:

```
Projects_GBR <- subset(Projects, Currency=="Pound Sterling")
```

I then create another dataframe, where I create a new column using mutate, where I then calculate the project from GBR to Euro.

```
Projects_GBR_Euro <- Projects_GBR %>%
  mutate(Total_Amount_Euro = Total_Amount*1.4)
```

*(1.4 is the currency to Euro)*

This works, but there must be a more straightforward way, where I won't need to create a new dataframe for each currency.

I have tried creating a For Loop also using if-functions, but nothing really seems to work as I recieve a whole bunch of warnings.

My For-Loop/If attempt:

```
Projects$Total_Amount_Euro <- 0

for (i in 1:nrow(Projects)){
  if(i == (Projects$Currency=="Pound Sterling")){
    Projects$Total_Amount_Euro <- Projects$Total_Amount*1.4 
  }
  i <- i+1
}
```

... and so on with the rest of the currencies.

I hope that someone is able to help me through this R-dilemma
- Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output? Do you have a table of the right exchange rates? If you have a column of exchange rates and a column of values, you can just multiply them together because `*` is vectorised in R. See what happens when you do `1:2 * 3:4`.

Comment: I have added a picure of the general setup of the columns in question...

The currency rates are not incorporated in the dataset - what I have done so far is find the exchange rates one at a time when trying to re-calculate to 1 currency (Euro). Also, (additional info) my dataset is pretty large with a few thousand rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using the package `rvest` in order to scrap exchange quotes from the web (here from bloomberg):

```
# creating a dummy data frame
USD <- runif(20, 3.5, 9.5)
GBP <- runif(20, 3.5, 9.5)
CHF <- runif(20, 3.5, 9.5)
dat <- cbind.data.frame(USD, GBP, CHF)

# prelims
currency.list <- c("USD", "GBP", "CHF")
main.currency <- "EUR"
url.list <- paste0("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/", currency.list, main.currency, ":CUR")
mylist <- data.frame(currency.list, url.list, stringsAsFactors = F)

#Loading the rvest package
require('rvest')

#Reading the HTML codes from the website
myfct <- function(url){
  require(rvest)
  wp <- read_html(url)
  rate <- html_text(html_nodes(wp, ".price"))
  return(rate)
}
rate <- as.numeric(sapply(url.list, myfct))
currency <- currency.list
rates <- data.frame(rate, currency)

# Converting to EUR
converted.dat <- t(t(dat)*rates$rate)
converted.dat <- data.frame(converted.dat)
names(converted.dat) <- paste0("Former ", names(converted.dat))
```

Here you we can compare the first couple of rows of `dat` and `converted.dat`:

```
> head(dat)
       USD      GBP      CHF
1 5.362443 4.800306 5.964169
2 4.212471 9.096019 8.102730
3 5.445699 8.156965 8.215501
4 5.237936 3.634849 5.998497
5 4.652035 7.281675 5.983482
6 4.698188 6.318771 7.331366

> head(converted.dat)
Former USD Former GBP Former CHF
1   4.339289   5.498271   5.090418
2   3.408732  10.418580   6.915680
3   4.406660   9.342988   7.011930
4   4.238538   4.163356   5.119717
5   3.764426   8.340430   5.106902
6   3.801774   7.237520   6.257321

> rates
    rate currency
1 0.8092      USD
2 1.1454      GBP
3 0.8535      CHF
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!! - I ended up combining both answers, but making a full_join with a dataset that had all the currencys and then multiplying the Award_Amount with the imported dataset with currencies.